# Warnings for function calls with too many parameters in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm warns about many issues (potential or real ones) in PHP code. Oftentimes, I see code like this:

```
function doSomething($a, $b) {
     // ...
}

$value = doSomething("1", "2", "3"); // the third parameter is superfluous!
```

I know that this is actually a feature of PHP but I would like more strict rules for my codebase. Can I make PhpStorm to show warnings for function calls with too many parameters?

Comment: I had a look in `Editor -> Inspections` settings page but either I'm blind or it can't be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
2. `PHP | Code Smell`
3. `Parameters number mismatch declaration`

Comment: @Pang Seems like it does not. You may file a ticket to their Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Answer (score 1):

I think a check of this sort falls more into a style (ala `java`'s `checkstyle`) category. `PHPStorm` integrates with [PHP Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer). Take a look at the docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html).

Code sniffer let's you define your own coding standard rules, so you could try adding a rule for this.